# Mapping of GraphQL ASP.Net Core 7 results to conflicting namespaces

Tags: graphql, webapi

[image]

Hi,

As you can see from the picture above, MapGraphQL has an ambiguous call error and there were two conflicting namespaces namely:

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapGraphQL
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.GraphQLHttpEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapGraphQL

Now this was the result of installing these packages:

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
3. HotChocolate.AspNetCore
4. HotChocolate.Data.EntityFramework
5. GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore

I tried the following using statements already just to test which one will work:

```
using MapGraphQL = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapGraphQL;
using MapGraphQL2 = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.GraphQLHttpEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapGraphQL;
```

By the way, I was following [this tutorial](https://blog.christian-schou.dk/how-to-implement-graphql-in-asp-net-core/) by Christian Schou when this happened.

I appreciate your help in advance in fixing this problem. I hope it helps others too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's conflicted with other function.
Try to add the parameter name as:

```
app.MapGraphQL(path: "/graphql");
```